# Power analysis for 3-level HLM model with lmer4 (longitudinal within person design)

Tags: multilevel-analysis, statistical-power

I have been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to do a power analysis using simr with a two-level multilevel model. I have observations nested in people and am trying to do a post-hoc power analysis (I know, I won't get much information from this). Of note, there is no random design to this study. Most examples I have seen are using treatment and controls and I have gotten turned around with how to do the following. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My lmer model is:

```
test <- lmer(ln_auc ~ zNSE_mean + waketimeday1 + zsoc_negaff + zp_soc_negaff + black + female + zincome + zpared + zstress_sum
            + (1 | id), data = na.omit(MADIC_hlm))
```

I then specify a new effect size for my main variable of interest.

```
fixef(test)["zNSE_mean"] <- .2
```

And finally I run the power simulation

```
powerSim(test, nsim = 1000)
```

I do not feel confident that I am setting this up correctly for my design. Any insights would be extremely valuable.